# PHP package install on CentOS

Tags: php, centos, yum

I want to figure out some issue in my CentOS server.

I have two packages that already installed in my server: `php-cli` and `php-common`. I see their details when i use the command `yum info`. However, when i use the command `yum install php-cli`, i get an offer to install these two packages, like they are not installed on the server at all. According to the `info` command, the packages that already installed have the same version of the packages that the server offering to install.

Anyone can explain that?

```
yum info php-cli
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.syn.co.il
 * epel: mirror.nonstop.co.il
 * extras: centos.syn.co.il
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
 * updates: centos.syn.co.il
Available Packages
Name        : php-cli
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.3.3
Release     : 48.el6_8
Size        : 2.2 M
Repo        : updates
Summary     : Command-line interface for PHP
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP
Description : The php-cli package contains the command-line interface
            : executing PHP scripts, /usr/bin/php, and the CGI interface.
```

---

```
yum info php-common
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.syn.co.il
 * epel: mirror.nonstop.co.il
 * extras: centos.syn.co.il
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
 * updates: centos.syn.co.il
Available Packages
Name        : php-common
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.3.3
Release     : 48.el6_8
Size        : 530 k
Repo        : updates
Summary     : Common files for PHP
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP
Description : The php-common package contains files used by both the php
            : package and the php-cli package.
```

---

```
yum install php-cli
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.syn.co.il
 * epel: mirror.nonstop.co.il
 * extras: centos.syn.co.il
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
 * updates: centos.syn.co.il
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-48.el6_8 for package: php-cli-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================
 Package                       Arch                      Version                            Repository                  Size
=============================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php-cli                       x86_64                    5.3.3-48.el6_8                     updates                    2.2 M
Installing for dependencies:
 php-common                    x86_64                    5.3.3-48.el6_8                     updates                    530 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)

Total download size: 2.7 M
Installed size: 9.1 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like those packages are installed, otherwise it would say `Installed Packages`, e.g.

```
Installed Packages
Name        : php-cli
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 0
Version     : 7.0.14
Release     : 1.fc25
Size        : 13 M
Repo        : @System
From repo   : updates
Summary     : Command-line interface for PHP
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP and Zend and BSD
Description : The php-cli package contains the command-line interface
            : executing PHP scripts, /usr/bin/php, and the CGI interface.
```

Comment: OK, Thanks. For some reason, I was sure that `yum info` presenting an info regarding an installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

As per man page of 'yum'

```
"info Is used to list a description and summary information about available packages".
```

Thus it is listing only packages, Available in repositories.enter code here